# Will Snowflake eliminate dummy columns in a CTE?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a CTE like this:

```
time_differences  as 
(
    select 
        datetime,
        user, 
        lag(datetime) over (partition by user order by datetime) next_event,
        COALESCE(datediff('MINUTE', next_event, log_datetime), 1) as minutes_until_next_event,
        minutes_until_next_event- 1 as time_offline 
    from 
        data_set
    order by 
        datetime, user
)
```

Here the columns `next_event` and `minutes_until_next_event` are dummy columns for readability. Will this affect performance or will the compiler automatically eliminate the columns internally?

Comment: Will snowflake eliminate "dummy" columns? No, why or how would it know their "dummy" columns used for "readability" ? Seeing the columns are part of a CTE, they will disappear in the end query if not referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake will optimise the query and execute it as efficiently as it can - based on the SQL provided, data volumes, partitioning, etc.

Splitting you calculation logic into multiple virtual columns is highly unlikely to have any impact on performance